# Kotlin: How do I get characters after "@" in a string?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, substring, string-interpolation

I have a string that is an email. I want to be able to get the domain part of the email no matter what the string/email is. Essentially I'm wanting to get hold of the characters after the @ part of the string. For example, for testing@kotlin.com, I'm after the **kotlin.com** part.

val emailString = "hello@world.com"

Comment: what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I know substring is most probably the best way to go about it but I'm not really familiar with startIndexes and endIndexes etc.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Would I be able to use Java and Kotlin in the same file?

Comment: Just search for it in google, first link: http://kotlination.com/kotlin/kotlin-split-string-example

Comment: @Fantini Straight to the point. Appreciate it

Comment: it uses the same API, kotlin extends Java, and compiles into java byte code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note**: [Ivan Wooll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47561575/7366707) brings up the point of using [`substringAfterLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-after-last.html), which is a very useful utility, though it is important to keep in mind that it **cannot return `null`** and instead defaults to a provided default value (this is the original string, if nothing is specified).

I personally prefer dealing with `null` in cases where invalid input is a reasonable concern, rather than e.g. an empty string, because it's a much clearer indication that the delimiter was not found, and this special case can be easily handled by chaining `?:`, `?.`, `let`, etc.

Here's an example of possibly-unwanted behavior:

```
string           | string.substringAfterLast("@")
-------------------------------------------------
"domain.com"     | "domain.com" !
"@domain.com"    | "domain.com"
"foo@domain.com" | "domain.com"
```

---

Just for the sake of completeness:

```
val string = "hello@world.com"

val index = string.indexOf('@')

val domain: String? = if (index == -1) null else string.substring(index + 1)
```

This assigns the part after `@` to `domain` if it exists, otherwise `null`.

---

For learning, IntelliJ's Java -> Kotlin converter may be of use.

By default, this shortcut is usually mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

You could even make this an extension property:

```
val String.domain: String?
    get() {
        val index = string.indexOf('@')
        return if (index == -1) null else string.substring(index + 1)
    }
```

and then you would be able to do

```
println("hello@world.com".domain)
```

You could shorten this code to one line with [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html):

```
string.indexOf('@').let { if (it == -1) null else string.substring(it + 1) }
```

---

Here's a [similar question in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498036/parse-rfc-2822-email-addresses-in-java).

Answer (score 52):

While there's nothing wrong with the accepted answer the Kotlin standard library is worth exploring as it contains nice little methods like `substringAfterLast`which would shorten the example to this

```
val string = "hello@world.com"

val domain: String? = string.substringAfterLast("@")
```

Comment: I like this one better. In this case, you don't even need the index value.

Comment: Nice find, though [`substringAfterLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-after-last.html) doesn't return a nullable string - the default value is the string itself. Whether this is desired depends on the use.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression describes the second substring be the delimiter character x

```
yourText.split('x')[1]
```